# opening a particular application always with admin privileges

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, privileges

Is there a way I can open a particular application always with *Admin Privileges* ? I mean to say , just double click the application and the application starts with the admin privileges.

I need to edit a lot of xml files in the `C:\` directory if windows.To save the edits to those files I need admin privileges.I have to always open the `notepad++` *(a text editor)* with the admin privileges. I do not like every time to right click the application and then run as admin.It takes time !

So is there a direct way ?

*NOTE : I don't want to turn this feature (admin) off*

Comment: Are you asking about [turning off the UAC prompt for a specific program](http://www.google.com/search?q=disable+uac+for+a+specific+program)?

Comment: @Synetech yeah...

Answer (score 2):

[Turning off the UAC prompt for specific programs](http://www.google.com/search?q=disable%20uac%20for%20a%20specific%20program), or [adding a program to a UAC “whitelist”](http://www.google.com/search?q=uac%20whitelist) have been common questions since Vista was released.

As you can see, there are *lots* of questions about it (many of them right here at SU). Unfortunately there is no practical solution to this because there is no “whitelist” (yet? still?)

Instead, you can use a non-ideal, convoluted [method using the Task Scheduler](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/run-uac-restricted-programs-without-the-uac-prompt/730) to bypass the UAC prompt for specific programs by creating a task, setting it to use admin privileges, and entering the username and password.

Otherwise, you have to either turn down/off the UAC setting or live with it. At least setting the program to always use Admin privileges via the shortcut or compatibility tab like the two suggestions given here helps a little.

Comment: I didn't get the method that tells you to make the shortcuts. [schtasks /run /TN "Launch Device Manager"](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/run-uac-restricted-programs-without-the-uac-prompt/730) Will it be different for notepad++ ?

Comment: Yes, you specify the executable for Notepad++ (e.g., `notepad++.exe`) in the *Program/script* field instead of `devemgmt.msc`, and you give the task a different name (e.g., `Notepad++` instead of `Launch Device Manager`). Then when you create the shortcut to the task, you specify that name (e.g., `schtasks /run /TN "Notepad++"`). Now you can run the shortcut to the task and it should open without displaying the UAC prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the program you want to run as admin then click **Properties** then go to the **Compatibility** tab then check **Run this program as an administrator**.

Comment: But that gives a UAC prompt. I don't want that

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get around that other than turning UAC off.

Answer (score 1):

ScriptLogic's Privilege Authority (http://www.scriptlogic.com/products/privilegeauthority/version-comparison.asp) can elevate specific applications.  The Community Edition is free.

Beyond Trust also has PowerBroker Desktops that has similar functionality, but I do not think there is a free version.  (http://www.beyondtrust.com/Products/PowerBroker-Desktops-Windows-Edition/)

There are other products that have this elevation functionality. They basically work by running as a service which is then able to change the privileges of other processes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a shortcut to Notepad++ and call it adminNotepad++
2. Right click on that shortcut and click Properties
3. Click Advanced and tick *Always run as administrator* -> OK -> Apply -> OK
4. Open Notepad++ from the shortcut you called adminNotepad++

Comment: will it give me a UAC prompt ?

Comment: ahh, windows 7. didn't notice that. give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Setting UAC to autoelevate would be my answer.

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee679793.aspx